# Unable to read Athena query into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

I have the below code, and want to get it to return a dataframe properly. The polling logic works, but the dataframe doesn't seem to get created/returned. Right now it just returns None when called.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import io
import re
import time

AK='mykey'
SAK='mysecret'

params = {
    'region': 'us-west-2',
    'database': 'default',
    'bucket': 'my-bucket',
    'path': 'dailyreport',
    'query': 'SELECT * FROM v_daily_report LIMIT 100'
}

session = boto3.Session(aws_access_key_id=AK,aws_secret_access_key=SAK)


# In[32]:


def athena_query(client, params):

    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString=params["query"],
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': params['database']
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://' + params['bucket'] + '/' + params['path']
        }
    )
    return response


def athena_to_s3(session, params, max_execution = 5):
    client = session.client('athena', region_name=params["region"])
    execution = athena_query(client, params)
    execution_id = execution['QueryExecutionId']
    df = poll_status(execution_id, client)
    return df

def poll_status(_id, client):
    '''
    poll query status
    '''
    result = client.get_query_execution(
        QueryExecutionId = _id
    )

    state = result['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']
    if state == 'SUCCEEDED':
        print(state)
        print(str(result))
        s3_key = 's3://' + params['bucket'] + '/' + params['path']+'/'+ _id + '.csv'
        print(s3_key)
        df = pd.read_csv(s3_key)
        return df
    elif state == 'QUEUED':
        print(state)
        print(str(result))
        time.sleep(1)
        poll_status(_id, client)
    elif state == 'RUNNING':
        print(state)
        print(str(result))
        time.sleep(1)
        poll_status(_id, client)
    elif state == 'FAILED':
        return result
    else:
        print(state)
        raise Exception


df_data = athena_to_s3(session, params)

print(df_data)
```

I plan to move the dataframe load out of the polling function, but just trying to get it to work as is right now.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to take a look at [AWS Wrangler](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler) instead of using the traditional boto3 Athena API. This newer and more specific interface to all things data in AWS including queries to Athena and giving more functionality.

```
import awswrangler as wr

df = wr.pandas.read_sql_query(
    sql="select * from table",
    database="database"
)
```

Thanks to @RagePwn comment it is worth checking [PyAthena](https://pypi.org/project/PyAthena/) as an alternative to the boto3 option to query Athena.

Comment: I ended up using pyathena, but will definitely look into awswrangler. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it is returning None, then it is because state == 'FAILED'. You need to investigate the reason it failed, which may be in 'StateChangeReason'.

```
{
    'QueryExecution': {
        'QueryExecutionId': 'string',
        'Query': 'string',
        'StatementType': 'DDL'|'DML'|'UTILITY',
        'ResultConfiguration': {
            'OutputLocation': 'string',
            'EncryptionConfiguration': {
                'EncryptionOption': 'SSE_S3'|'SSE_KMS'|'CSE_KMS',
                'KmsKey': 'string'
            }
        },
        'QueryExecutionContext': {
            'Database': 'string'
        },
        'Status': {
            'State': 'QUEUED'|'RUNNING'|'SUCCEEDED'|'FAILED'|'CANCELLED',
            'StateChangeReason': 'string',
            'SubmissionDateTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            'CompletionDateTime': datetime(2015, 1, 1)
        },
        'Statistics': {
            'EngineExecutionTimeInMillis': 123,
            'DataScannedInBytes': 123,
            'DataManifestLocation': 'string',
            'TotalExecutionTimeInMillis': 123,
            'QueryQueueTimeInMillis': 123,
            'QueryPlanningTimeInMillis': 123,
            'ServiceProcessingTimeInMillis': 123
        },
        'WorkGroup': 'string'
    }
}
```

Comment: actually the state == SUCCEEDED when it ends. I can also see the results for that QueryExecutionId in S3.

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on the [RagePwn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1970684/ragepwn)'s answer of using `PyAthena` -that's what I ultimately did as well. For some reason `AwsWrangler` choked on me and couldn't handle the **JSON** that was being returned from S3. Here's the code snippet that worked for me based on [PyAthena's PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/PyAthena/#as-dataframe)

```py
import os
from pyathena import connect
from pyathena.util import as_pandas


aws_access_key_id = os.getenv('ATHENA_ACCESS_KEY')
aws_secret_access_key = os.getenv('ATHENA_SECRET_KEY')
region_name = os.getenv('ATHENA_REGION_NAME')
staging_bucket_dir = os.getenv('ATHENA_STAGING_BUCKET')

cursor = connect(aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                 aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                 region_name=region_name,
                 s3_staging_dir=staging_bucket_dir,
                ).cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
df = as_pandas(cursor)
```

The above assumes you have defined as environment variables the following:

- **ATHENA_ACCESS_KEY**: the AWS access key id for your AWS account
- **ATHENA_SECRET_KEY**: the AWS secret key
- **ATHENA_REGION_NAME**: the AWS region name
- **ATHENA_STAGING_BUCKET**: a bucket in the same account that has the correct access settings (explanation of which is outside the scope of this answer)